# Enable GPU accelerated div scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, electron

I am trying to make an slideshow animation run smoother on a low-powered device. I can easily make a similar animation run smoothly (60 FPS) by using css transforms and transitions. I believe in that case it is hardware accelerated, because the CPU is barely occupied during the animation.

However, the effect I want to optimize uses the built in scrolling, by setting a `div` to `overflow-x: scroll`, and putting multiple images next to each other in the `div`. It then uses scroll snapping to create a kind of carousel. When I scroll this, the CPU is close to 100% occupied and it is a bit laggy. Is there a way to make the built-in-scrolling more smooth or hardware accelerated (like the animations can be)? I know on mobile this is definitely the case, but this is on the desktop (Electron / Chrome). This codepen has an [example of the effect](https://codepen.io/jmansour/pen/wvKxxMg).

I tried applying `tranform: translateZ(0)` to either the container, or the elements in the container, hoping it would force them to be on a GPU layer, but it had no obvious effect.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick especially on ipad and chrome with the `backface-visibility`

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;

-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-perspective: 1000;

-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```